# Is there another equivalent property to MaximumExecutionTime and DisableMD5Validation in Azure.Storage.Blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am migrating from Microsft.Azure.Storage to Azure.Storage.Blobs. and while uploading the stream to the cloud,i need to set the max execution time as well as diabling the MD5 validation.Previously it was done with the BlobRequestOptions.MaxExecutionTime and BlobRequestOptions.DisableContentMD5Validation.But I'm unable to find this equivalent setting in BlobUploadOptions.Can somebody help please?

Comment: There is no property known as MaximumExecutionTime and DisableMD5Validation in Azure.Storage.Blob.

Those properties are available in legacy version of Azure SDK for .NET but not in the latest versions of Azure SDK for .NET.

Refer- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobuploadoptions?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cancellation tokens to cancel the tasks after certain time.

> CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new >CancellationTokenSource();
> cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

For ContentMD5Validation

> V12 does not have an automated mechanism for blob content validation. It must be done per-request by the user.

REFERENCES:

1. [Maximum execution time](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/AzureStorageNetMigrationV12.md#maximum-execution-time)
2. [Content Hashes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/AzureStorageNetMigrationV12.md#content-hashes)